# What is the best of passing taskHandle to another class in freeRTOS with pointers

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, freertos

OK it was not wise to ask question with some assumptions. Here is the detailed version.

I have 2 task, 1 for MQTT and 1 for LED. I want to read a data over MQTT and take an action to turn on an LED.

Here is my task declarations:

```
void taskMqtt(void *param);
xTaskHandle handleTaskMqtt;

void taskLed(void *param);
xTaskHandle handleTaskLed;
```

Here is the task creation part

```
status = xTaskCreate(taskMqtt, "taskMqtt", 4096, NULL, 2, handleTaskMqtt);
configASSERT(status == pdPASS);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "taskMqtt CREATED");
    
status = xTaskCreate(taskLed, "taskLed", 4096, NULL, 2, &handleTaskLed);
configASSERT(status == pdPASS);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "taskLed CREATED");
```

I created my Mqtt object like this and it works fine.

```
Mqtt mqtt("192.168.137.212", move(uptrWifi), handleTaskLed);
```

Here is the Mqtt.h file to observe class declaration

```
class Mqtt
{
private:
std::unique_ptr<Wifi> uptrWifi;
static xTaskHandle handlerTask;

static const char *subscribeTopic;
static const char *publishTopic;

static esp_mqtt_client_config_t _mqttCfg;
static esp_mqtt_client_handle_t _clientCfg;

static void mqttEventHandler(void *arg, esp_event_base_t eventBase, int32_t eventId, void *eventData);

public:
Mqtt(const char *brokerIp, std::unique_ptr<Wifi> uptrToWifi, xTaskHandle taskToNotify);
void init(void);
void sendDataOverMqtt(std::string title, int data);
void sendDataOverMqtt(std::string title, int data, std::string pubTopic);
static void getDataOverMqtt(char *data, int dataLen);

void setTopics(std::string subTopic, std::string pubTopic);
};
```

In Mqtt.cpp file I defined

```
xTaskHandle Mqtt::handlerTask;
```

and constructor

```
Mqtt::Mqtt(const char *brokerIp, std::unique_ptr<Wifi> uptrToWifi, 
xTaskHandle taskToNotify)
{
_mqttCfg.host = brokerIp;
ESP_LOGI("MQTT_H", "MQTT BROKER IP SET\n");

uptrWifi = move(uptrToWifi);
handlerTask = taskToNotify;
}
```

and here is my function for read data and forward to the LED task.

```
void Mqtt::getDataOverMqtt(char *data, int dataLen)
{
static uint32_t valueToSend = 1;

if (strncmp(data, "Led ON", 6) == 0)
{
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "\nDATA COMES \n");

    if (handlerTask != NULL)
    {
        xTaskNotify(handlerTask, valueToSend, eSetValueWithOverwrite);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNULL pointer\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    printf("\nCMD=%.*s\n\n", dataLen, data);
}
else if (strncmp(data, "Led OFF", 7) == 0)
{
    printf("\nCMD=%.*s\n\n", dataLen, data);
}
}
```

And here is the LED task

```
void taskLed(void *param)
{
uint32_t ulNotifiedValue = false;

while (1)
{
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "LED WAITING");

    xTaskNotifyWait(0, ULONG_MAX, &ulNotifiedValue, portMAX_DELAY);
    
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "\n NOTIFICATION \n");

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "LED TASK RUNNING");
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
}
}
```

When I run the code and sent Led ON command, I can see the logs

```
LED WAITING (from taskLED definition)
DATA COMES (from getDataOverMqtt definition)
Null Pointer (from getDataOverMqtt definition)
```

After that I was hoping to see on the logs

```
NOTIFICATION (from taskLED defition)
```

////////////////////////////////////// ORIGINAL POST BEFORE EDITS IS BELOW

I am trying to learn FreeRtos and C++.

I need to pass taskHandle to another class and want to use them for notify function. What is the best way to do that?

In taskControl.cpp file I created tasks as below.

```
void task1(void *param);
TaskHandle_t handleTask1;

void task2(void *param);
TaskHandle_t handleTask2;


status = xTaskCreate(task1, "task1", 4096, NULL, 2, &handleTask1);
configASSERT(status == pdPASS);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "task1 CREATED");
        
status = xTaskCreate(task2, "task2", 4096, NULL, 2, &handleTask2);
configASSERT(status == pdPASS);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "task2 CREATED");
```

I thought I can pass handleTask2 into another class via constructor

```
M m(&handleTask2);
```

In classM.h file, M is declared as below

```
class M
{
private:
    static TaskHandle_t *handlerTask;
public:
    M(TaskHandle_t *taskToNotify)
    {
        handlerTask = taskToNotify;
    }
};
```

And I tried to use handlerTask as below in classM.cpp file.

```
xTaskNotify(&handlerTask, valueToSend, eSetValueWithoutOverwrite);
```

What am I missing? What is the correct way to do this kind of thing?

Sorry for if my question is not clear.

Comment: what is `xTaskHandle` ? Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. Currently it is unclear what is the issue in your code, because the code you posted has so many errors that are most likely unrelated to the actual issues

Comment: I updated it as TaskHandle_t https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html

There could be errors since I just want to write simple without an actual code.

Comment: what happened when you tried? Did you get a compiler error? `xTaskNotify` expects a handle,not a pointer to a handle https://www.freertos.org/xTaskNotify.html

Comment: Nothing happened. I did not get the notification.

Comment: you should explain in the question what you expect the code to do and what happened instead. Currently you are asking for "the best", which is problematic because a) "best" is purely opinion based and b) confusing/misleading when you are actually searching for something that just works

Comment: Is `mqtt` object global?